# Variable DC offset with op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to make amplifier that its output is Vo = -Vi +Voff  where vi is my input signal while Voff is offset signal come from power supply of amplifier 15v  , Voff  vary from -5v  to +5 V  by variable resistor 100k

It tried with this design i get Ri = Rf
but i have problem when get value of Rx every time i get negative value
[image]

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried?

Comment: if +/-15V total across 100K Pot with tap to Rx to Vin(-)  then pot gain=1/3 to get +/-5V out or Rx= 300k, Rf=100k=Ri & Vin+=0

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make two assumptions here that I suspect were implicit in the original problem statement.

1. The 100K 'variable resistor' is actually a potentiometer, not just a variable resistor.
2. The power supplies are actually +/-15V, not just +15

Now if you draw an inverting amplifier, Vo = -Vin you need only two equal value resistors (value to be determined but probably something in the range of 10K-1M)

Connect one end of the potentiometer to +15 and the other end to -15. now you have a voltage source that varies from +15 to -15 as you rotate the pot, and it has a source resistance of 0\$\Omega\$ to 25K\$\Omega\$ depending on the pot rotation (maximum at mid-rotation).

There's an implicit requirement not to have the pot response too nonlinear, so we would not want to load the pot wiper too heavily, but say 100K (say to ground or something similar) would be fine. If you loaded it with (say) 1K the last little bit of rotation on either end would do most of the work and it would be very fussy to set and probably not very stable.

That's enough of a hint for now, see if my assumptions and the suggestions above lead anywhere for you.

Comment: When you come up with your answer you are free to add it and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Vo = -Vi +Voff opamp circuit. Ok, I will draw you it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSnLK0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
You see, you go into the inverted side with the signal to get your inverted signal, then we "add" the offset voltage on the non inverting side at the point that I refer to as the Vref input (the zero crossing reference) that is on the non inverting side of this inverting op amp design after R1. Typically R1's reference is the DC ground, but in your application this is where you inject your offset voltage at.

The cool thing about this site is I can draw a quick schematic. I didn't go trough all of the design of it, so the circuit simulation will not work, and I wanted to illustrate the input circuit.